# Issue with transparent images on a transparent background

Tags: css, iframe, png, transparency, gif

I have a weird issue with a graphic with rounded corners.

I have a HTML page with the body set to transparent (style="filter:alpha(opacity=100);opacity:100;background-color:transparent;") and within this body is a div with a PNG image with rounded corners, with transparency on the edges so that it transitions correctly with the background.

This HTML page is contained within an iFrame on top of another HTML page, so I want the transparent image contained within the iFrame to show through and thus  the rounded image to transition correctly with the background (which is an image) on the page that is calling the iFrame (hence the body within the iFrame has a transparent background).

This actually works fine, except for the transparency on the rounded corners. For some reason there's a very fine but noticeable jagged black edging around the rounded corner, as if a black matte was put on it.

I have also tried it with transparent GIFs, but got jagged white edgings instead.

Has anyone ever tried to do something like this before, and got it to work? If so, I'd love to hear how.

***EDIT***
Here's a link to the result: [image](http://www.iandevlin.net/pics/searchtemp.png)
The image with the leaves is the background image (Flash) of the calling HTML. The search box is contained an an iFrame with a transparent background.

This happens on IE7. Firefox seems ok, oddly enough.

Comment: Can you give us (a link to) the picture? Also, is this consistent between browsers?

Comment: Which browser do you use? IE6 can't handle pngs.

Comment: @stefita, IE6 *can* handle them with some assistance. See my answer below.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that it was hapening on IE only, but on IE7., as I'm aware that IE6 can't handle PNGs unless you use some fix (which I am already). Will sort out a link to the picture.

Comment: @Ian Devlin: I meant the original image, not the result.

Answer (score 1):

You have set Transparency on the body tag to 100... This means its not transparent, for it to be fully transparent you would have to set it to 0. But doing this will result in all elements contained in the body tag to be transparent as well.

I think something similar is happening, the search box is inheriting the opacity attribute which you set.

If you remove the opacity settings what happens?

Also check this website out, http://www.domedia.org/oveklykken/css-transparency.php

Comment: Yeah, thanks for that, my mistake, those values are clearly not needed!

Removing them causes the same result unfortunately.

Thanks for that link, but rgba doesn't seem to be making a difference.